# list from .select_related("...")

Tags: python, django, list, django-models

Is there a direct way to convert a query like this:

```
query_db = Example.objects.all()
selected_db = Example.select_related("...")

print(type(selected_db))
...
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

...into a list? I know there are ways to do it afterwards, but are there functions like for example...

```
...values_list("...", flat=True)
```

...to solve this directly in the query?

Comment: Please *don't* use `.values(..)` or `.values_list()`. These should only be used in very specific cases, for example where you perform a `GROUP BY` on certain field(s).

Comment: This is a specific case of the primitive obsession antipattern: https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession

Comment: Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it. For example:

entry_list = list(Entry.objects.all())

Comment: @Adelin: `.values_list` does not force evaluation either. In fact it does *not* produce a list, it produces a `QuerySet`. that contains tuples. Unfortunately the `__repr__` presents it as a list.